# can one instance of google clouds compute engine have multiple external ip addresses

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using google cloud compute engin for running a small web server as well as some other servers I currently am using the free trial I will be upgrading to a paid account when that expires but I would like to have another server on a different wan IP address I know I can use a different port and do forwarding/redirects but my question is can one instance ger multiple external IPs or would I need to create/pay for another instance to get a 2nd external IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create VM instance with multiple external IPs.

Have a look at the documentation [Creating instances with multiple network interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces):

> By default, every instance in a VPC network has a single default
>   network interface. Use these instructions to create additional network
>   interfaces. Each interface is attached to a different VPC network,
>   giving that instance access to different VPC networks in Google Cloud
>   Platform (GCP). You cannot attach multiple network interfaces to the
>   same VPC network.

and at the section [Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#requirements):

> - You can only configure a network interface when you create an instance.
> - Each network interface configured in a single instance must be attached to a different VPC network, and each interface must belong to
>     a subnet whose IP range does not overlap with the subnets of any other
>     interfaces.
> - The additional VPC networks that the multiple interfaces will attach to must exist before you create the instance. See [Using VPC Networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc)
>     for instructions on creating additional VPC networks.
> - You cannot delete a network interface without deleting the instance.

and

> - Every interface can optionally have an external IP address.

I've tried to create such VM:

1. create [custom VPC networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#create-custom-network):

   ```
   $ gcloud compute networks create test-vpc-network-1 --subnet-mode=custom
   $ gcloud compute networks create test-vpc-network-2 --subnet-mode=custom
   ```
2. create [custom VPC subnets](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#add-subnets):

   ```
   $ gcloud compute networks subnets create test-subnet-1 --network=test-vpc-network-1 --region=europe-west3 --range=172.16.1.0/24
   $ gcloud compute networks subnets create test-subnet-2 --network=test-vpc-network-2 --region=europe-west3 --range=172.16.2.0/24
   ```
3. [reserve static external IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) (optional):

   ```
   $ gcloud compute addresses create test-static-ip-1 --region=europe-west3
   $ gcloud compute addresses create test-static-ip-2 --region=europe-west3
   ```
4. create VM instance:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create test-instance-2ip --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --network-interface subnet=test-subnet-1,address=34.89.215.180 --network-interface subnet=test-subnet-2,address=35.234.123.210 --tags=test-instance-2ip --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200430 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud --boot-disk-device-name=test-instance-2ip
   ```

   and here it is VM instance with 2 external IPs:

   ```
   NAME               ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP            EXTERNAL_IP                   STATUS
   test-instance-2ip  europe-west3-a  n1-standard-1               172.16.1.3,172.16.2.2  XXX.89.XXX.180,XXX.234.XXX.210  RUNNING
   ```
5. don't forget to [create firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules):

   ```
   $ gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-instance-2ip-vpc-1 --direction=INGRESS --priority=900 --network=test-vpc-network-1 --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp,udp --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=test-instance-2ip
   $ gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-instance-2ip-vpc-2 --direction=INGRESS --priority=900 --network=test-vpc-network-2 --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp,udp --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=test-instance-2ip
   ```

   rules above are for example only.

In addition, have look at 3rd party [example](https://medium.com/faun/creating-instances-with-multiple-network-interfaces-and-ip-route-issue-on-google-cloud-platform-6ac24977613e).

Also, as a possible alternative you can try [Protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/):

> You can set up multiple forwarding rules to point to a single target
>   instance, allowing you to use multiple external IP addresses with one
>   VM instance. You can use this in scenarios where you may want to serve
>   data from just one VM instance, but through different external IP
>   addresses. This is especially useful for setting up SSL virtual
>   hosting.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted to do, I cannot find a list of regions for creating the VPC subnets do you know where I could find a list of all available regions?

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. Please accept or upvote my answer if it was helpful for you. Sure, have a look at the documentation [Regions and Zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) section [Locations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#locations)

Comment: I have accepted your answer but when I try to run the command to create the instance it gives an error I have changed the region to us-east1 how can I find what IP addresses to use for that reagin?

Error:

 - Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP': '34.89.215.180'. The specified external IP address '34.89.215.180' was not found in region 'us-east1'.

Comment: i found that the address parameter is only for static IPs after removing it now it works

Comment: Great! In my example I  used static IPs, but it's not required. More examples you can find in the documentation [Creating instances with multiple network interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces).